# Adding a Elasticsearch node, do I need to copy internal_users.yml file and the other configuration?

Tags: elasticsearch

At each time I added a node to a cluster, I used to copy internal_users.yml and similar files to the new node before starting it to keep the same users and roles configuration. Maybe it is not necessary? What is the best way to proceed with the configuration related to users when adding a new node?

Using Opendistro

Thanks

Comment: what does `the same users and roles configuration` mean exactly ?

Comment: I wanted to say about the internal_users.yml file. If I add a new node the previously created users are not present in the default configuration. I dont know if this file will be syncronized after connecting the cluster... thanks